# Dell SAS 6/iR WMI classes

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, wmi, hardware-raid

FIrst off Im not very familiar with WMI at all, but what Im trying to accomplish is pulling the raid status out off some wmi class for a SAS 6/iR.

I figured as much as installing the Megaraid Storage Manager v2.90 who suppousedly includes a WMI provider, according to services it seems to be running aswell.

However I have no idea what class to pull to get the desired information. Anyone have any idea how to go about this? Ive been trying to browse the classes in hope of stumbling upon something from this provider but no luck this far.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Would you be opposed to switching to SNMP? Dell provides SNMP Data for all of their hardware, i'm fairly certain you need OMSA install but you already did that right?

Comment: Good point. Already considered SNMP through OMSA as a fallback option. Thing is I already have NSClient++ installed and it has a fairly nice WMI module that allows me to query through WQL, thus I can implement the raid-check seamlessy on the serverside for Nagios to pull through NRPE. No need for a windows/dell/snmp specialized check on the Nagios side. I think this is to be preferred for simplicity. :-)  But your alternative is an option if I cannot make heads or tails of the WMI provider for the raid controller.

Comment: Id like to add that unfortunately the SLI MegaRAID package did not provide any WMI classes at all, however omsa does, but it seems not to provide any WMI for the raid controller even though it is available in the webinterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot find any documentation, your only other option is that WMI is largely self documenting. But to work through this will require more WMI knowledge. And while you can find WMI namespaces, classes and properties; without documentation working out what values mean may not be possible.

As a starter, to find all the WMI namespaces on your system, use the following PowerShell:

```
function RecureseWmiNamespaces {
  param([string]$ns = "root")

  Get-WmiObject -class "__NAMESPACE" -namespace $ns | Foreach-Object -process {
    $n = "$ns\$($_.Name)"
    $n
    RecureseWmiNamespaces $n
  }
}
RecureseWmiNamespaces
```

Any namespace with "Dell" in its name is likely to be of interest.

EDIT: There are tools to help exploration out there, check out "WMI Explorer" here http://www.primaltools.com/downloads/communitytools/.

Answer (score 1):

I would also try searching for MOF files other than standard ones (in the WBEM directory). If Dell included a WMI provider there are likely to be MOF files accompanying it that you can use to figure out the installed namespaces and classes.

Comment: On 64bit OS, note there will be two folders: Windows\System32\wbem for 64bit providers (and core WMI) and Windows\SysWOW64\wbem for 32bit.